# Understanding a sentence about starting up jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, head

**What is the definition of `entire page` in the [following line](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)?**

> When the entire page is included via PHP include() or require()
>   function, make sure to put that script
>   code inside the `<body>` tag and not
>   inside the `<head>`, because calling
>   jQuery script file from inside the
>    tag doesn't work for some
>   reason.

I have had problems in setting up a jQuery codes. 
However, I managed to get one to work by putting it inside `HEAD` and the following code

## #1 code

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    --- code here---- 
});
```

I have not managed to get any functions to work. 
I have had them inside and outside the code #1. The following is an example.

## #2 Not working code

```
    function notEmpty() {                        
        //put this in a function and call it when the user tries to submit
        var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
        if(tags == '' || tags == null) {         
            alert('Please enter one or more tags');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I use PHP to include the tags HTML, HEAD, /HEAD and BODY by the following code in my index.php.

## #3 Code by which sources HTML, HEAD and body tags

```
 include ( './official_content/html_head_body.php' );
```

Comment: Good question. Docs aren't very specific here.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! - I accept Votey's answer because of good explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that statement suspect.  I've never encountered any problem including the `<script>` tag for jQuery in the `<head>` of the document, like any other `<script>` tag.  The browser cannot be aware of anything that PHP has done.  I suspect it is simply a misstatement.

To address your specific code, what you've written in #1 is entirely correct.  Passing a function to `$(document).ready()` lets you supply code to be run when the document is "ready" (meaning: when the page itself has loaded, without necessarily having loaded external resources like images, stylesheets, et cetera, for which you wouldn't want to have to wait).

Regarding #2, that function is not using jQuery at all; it's using only built-in JavaScript functions.  Having said that, it should work correctly by finding a form element with `id="tags"` and showing an alert box if that element has an empty `value`.  How were you calling this function?  In the world of jQuery, you'd do something like this:

```
$("#id-of-your-form").submit(notEmpty);
```

You could also rewrite the `notEmpty()` function to exploit jQuery like so:

```
function notEmpty() {{
    var tags = $("#tags").val();
    if (tags == '' || tags == null) {
        alert('Please enter one or more tags');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Again, the rest of that function currently connects to jQuery at all.  It's fine just the way it is there.

Finally, #3 is unrelated to jQuery, since that's processing happening within PHP, of which JavaScript remains entirely unaware.

Comment: i concur. not ever seen this problem and find the 'sentence' questionable

Answer (score 2):

Put the jQuery source in the html_head_body.php file and add your function in your "content" php file.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

       function notEmpty() {                        
         //put this in a function and call it when the user tries to submit
         var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
         if(tags == '' || tags == null) {         
            alert('Please enter one or more tags');
            return false;
         }
         return true;
       }

     });
   </script>         
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have now two `$(document).ready(function(){`: one in HEAD and one in BODY. -- **Can this be a problem?**